# What is the problem name for Traveling salesman problem(TSP) without considering going back to starting point in asymetric graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, traveling-salesman

need to visit all the nodes exactly once and without considering going back to starting point in an asymetric graph.The distance should be minimum.
Like a traveller needs to visit all the cities with minimum distance/cost and don't need to go back to the starting node. and addition to that the graph is asymetric. like the distance from A->B and B->A is different.
is there any way for doing this?

Comment: Your variant doesn't seam to simplify the TSP so you could use any TSP algorithm and adapt it to your variant. I'm sure it is still NP-hard.

Comment: This is sometimes called the shortest Hamiltonian path.